# Pass name through `map()` to be evaluated lazily

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation, purrr

I'm making a series of plots programmatically, and I want to pass the name of the tibble (or dataframe) into the title of my ggplot2 plot, so I know which is which.

`deparse(substitute(x))` works for making a single plot from a tibble, but outputs `"."` when called via `purrr::map()` when making plots from a list of tibbles.

```r
#initialize data frame
myDf <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = sample(1:10, 5))

#initialize function
myPlot <- function(df) {
    title = deparse(substitute(df))
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_col() +
        ggtitle(title)
}

#call function
myPlot(myDf)
```

This gives me a plot with the title `myDF`.

Now I want to do the same thing with a list of plots:

```r
#initialize list of data frames
myDFs <- vector("list", 0)
myDFs$first  <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = sample(1:10, 5))
myDFs$second <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = sample(1:10, 5))
myDFs$third  <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = sample(1:10, 5))

#initialize same function
myPlot <- function(df) {
    title = deparse(substitute(df))
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_col() +
        ggtitle(title)
}

#call function with purrr::map
map(myDFs, myPlot)
```

Now each is titled with the same title: `.x[[i]]`

I'd love to know how to pass a more informative title through map.  It doesn't have to be pretty, but it does have to be unique.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `imap` which is made for such operations

```
myPlot <- function(df, names) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_col() +
   ggtitle(names)
}

purrr::imap(myDFs, myPlot)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(myPlot, myDFs, names(myDFs))
```

---

Or using `iwalk`

```
purrr::iwalk(myDFs, ~ myPlot(.x, .y))
```

where

```
myPlot <- function(data, nameVec){
    ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_col() +
      ggtitle(nameVec)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the walk function!  To try it, I had to slightly update my function to save the plot and then print it on a separate line, but it's nice not having it display to the screen!